Alt+Tab doesn't work in LXQT
Fresh and latest version of LXQT. Alt+Tab doesn't work at all.
Is it how it's supposed to be? I've done a search and found only 1 or 2 results which proposed a tangled solution.
How to make this the way it does on any other Linux?

have you looked at your keyboard shortcuts?

@cinemassacres. No. Where?  And why would I given that a) it's a fresh installation b) on each Linux and almost any other OS Alt+Tab  works properly

on lxqt it's defaulted to control alt tab you can change it in the keyboard shortcuts to alt + tab

control alt tab  --> it doesn't work either
